# Finite Difference: Non-linear diffusion coefficient

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, heat-equation, finite-difference-methods

$$ u_t = \nabla \cdot (k(u) \nabla u) $$

---

I have read some posts on FDM for $k=k(x)$. How does the method extend in the non-linear case: $k = k(u)$.

I have attempted the following:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(  k(u) \frac{\partial u }{\partial x}\right) &= k(u)  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + k'(u)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)^2\\
&= k(u_i)\frac{u_{i+1}-2u_i+u_{i-1}}{h^2} + k'(u_i)\left(\frac{u_{i+1}-u_{i-1}}{2h}\right)^2
\end{align*}

Is this appropriate? Please suggest some further reading. Thanks.

Comment: It should be $$(k(u)u_{x})_{x} = k(u) u_{xx} + k'(u) \color{red}{u_{x}^{2}}$$

Comment: @mattos Oh, I see. I will edit it, thanks. Can you comment on the difference formula?

Comment: What is there to comment on? There are multiple ways to discretise your problem, some better than others, but there is no 'appropriate' one. I suppose you'll have difficulty dealing with the nonlinear term if you use an _implicit_ scheme of any sort because then you'll be dealing with a nonlinear algebraic equation to solve at each iteration, so you will require a root finding algorithm (Newton, bisection etc.) which can be computationally expensive.

Comment: @mattos Thanks. I am hoping my FD discretization is correct. I am trying to implement FTCS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is usually unwise do such splitting. $q = k(u) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is a physical quantity, usually referred to as "flux". This spatial operator usually is discretized using
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(
k(u) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
\right) \sim
\frac{q_{i+1/2} - q_{i-1/2}}{h} = 
\frac{k_{i+1/2} (u_{i+1} - u_i) - k_{i-1/2} (u_i - u_{i-1})}{h^2}. \tag{*}
$$
One may notice resemblance with finite volume approach.

This is a second order discretization provided that $k_{i\pm1/2}$ approximates $k(u_{i\pm1/2})$ with second order. There are several ways to approximate $k_{i\pm1/2}$. Common cases include:
$$k_{i+1/2} = \frac{k(u_i) + k(u_{i+1})}{2}\\
k_{i+1/2} = k\left(\frac{u_i + u_{i+1}}{2}\right)\\
k_{i+1/2} = \frac{2k(u_i) k(u_{i+1})}{k(u_i) + k(u_{i+1})}.$$
For different problems different choice for $k_{i+1/2}$ may be preferred. Choice may be done by running method against test problems with known solutions.

The (*) approximation has some good properties:

- Implicit methods have diagonally-dominant matrix for the unknown $u_i$ values.
- It is a conservative discretization (numerical method will preserve some integral like mass or energy). This is important if your problem has discontinuous solutions or solutions with sharp gradients.

Comment: I have not learned FVM and I'm trying to implement FDM (explicit) for this problem. Are you suggesting that it won't work?

Comment: I don't have analytical results to compare the numerical solution but when I compare the results of non-linear discretization with a linear case, the results show similar trends and behaviour. This might suggest that the approach is not totally invalid?

Comment: @DubsVeer23 It is not invalid. Just some (useful) physical properties may be lost if solution has jumps. For problems with smooth solutions you may see no difference.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea about handling zero flux boundaries here?

Comment: @DubsVeer23 Lust plug $q_{1/2} = 0$ or $q_{N-1/2} = 0$ in the (*).

Comment: Typo: Lust -> Just

Comment: Ok. Is it $q_{N+1/2} = 0$ (index $i = 1:N$) ? Also, for the FDM case, I am assuming that the point $i=-1$ has the same properties as $i=1$, so the flux across the left boundary is zero. This leads to $$ u^{n+1}_1 =( k^n_1 \cdot \Delta t) \frac{2u^n_2-2u^n_1}{h^2}$$

Comment: A similar treatment of the left boundary is carried out.

Comment: What are the coordinates of the boundaries snd the grid points $x_i$? My answer was for boundaries at $x = 0, L$ and grid $x_i = (i-1/2) h, i = 1,...,N$. In such case boundaries are at $x_{1/2}$ and $x_{N+1/2}$. If $x_i = ih, i=0,..., N$ you may zero out mean flux at the boundary $(q_{-1/2} + q_{1/2})/2 =0$. This gives your formula exactly

Comment: Yeah, my nodes and boundaries coincide. I am assuming that the (two) points left (ghost point) and right of the boundary at $x = 0$ are exactly the same, which results in zero flux: $$ i = 1: (k,u)_{0} \sim (k,u)_{2} \implies (ku_x)_x \Big|_{x=0} = 0  $$

Comment: I am hoping this approach is valid. I am not sure.